# maven archetype plugin - No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog

Tags: apache, maven, archetypes

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T09:58:13+02:00)
```

Fetching dependencies from the central repository works very well.
I have a problem with fetching archetypes though.

For example I am trying to use an archetype which is present in the central archetype catalog:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=sample-ear -DarchetypeArtifactId=wildfly-javaee7-webapp-ear-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=org.wildfly.archetype -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Maven fails. It basically cannot see any archetypes in the remote catalog:

```
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[WARNING] Specified archetype not found.
```

I am able to access the HTTP link for the catalog in a browser.

Documentation (http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html) states clearly:

> The Archetype Plugin knows by default about its internal catalog. It also knows about the **local** and **remote** catalogs.
>
> **remote** represents the http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml catalog file.

Have you ever had such issue ?
I would be grateful for any hint that could direct me to find a solution.

Comment: **[SOLVED]** Today morning I have run the very same command. This time the result was different. First of all a connection to Maven Central was successfully established. I have no idea why was it different yesterday. Additionally, as written by Anton below, we need to ad archetypeVersion to get the item from remote.

Answer (score 3):

Add option -DarchetypeVersion=8.2.0.Final

Comment: Yes, thank you. This was also required at the end, but let me avoid marking it as a solution, because the primary issue was some random connection problem. Anyway, thanks!